# How can I update a transaction from Electrum?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

I have not got my bitcoins confirmed in my wallet and when I try to double spend I keep getting errors mainly:
An outpoint is already spent in [DBBitcoinTx{txIndex=224965012, ip=51.254.44.148, time=1487879550, size=192, distinctIn=null, distinctOut=null, note='null', blockIndexes=[], nTxInput=1, nTxOutput=1}] [OutpointImpl{txIndex=224909177, txOutputN=3}]

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: @sr_gi: While that question is related, I'd disagree. The asker is already aware of the issue and trying to alleviate the problem, but is asking for help with a specific approach in a specific wallet.

Comment: @Murch I thoght that since the problem seems to be he is trying to double spend an UTXO from a transaction that is not getting confirmed, the problem was the same.